# DB2 - string match-inner join

Tags: db2, inner-join, sql-like

I didn't find much info on inner joins with substring.
I am not very well versed in SQL and I am trying to do a string match here but am getting a problem with the `LIKE` operator in the `INNER JOIN` clause.

I have data in Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 for example has JUY and Table 2 has Tyy_ss_JUY. Both the tables have over 10000 entires. I want to match both and give me a result when it matches the string.

Assume that I have two tables as follows:

```
Table1
LocationID Model          CAMERA
1          Zone A         ABCD
2          Zone B         ALI
3          Zone A         JUY
4          Zone A         LOS
5          Zone C         OMG
```

```
Table2   
Vehicle   NAME
Honda     Txx_ss_ABCD
Myvi      Tyy_ss_ABCD
Vios      Tyy_ss_JUY
Proton    Tyy_ss_LOS
SUV       Tyb_ss_OMG
SUV       UUS_ss_OMG
SUV       Lyx_ss_JUY
```

```sql
SELECT Vehicle,NAME
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN (SELECT CAMERA FROM Table1 WHERE Model LIKE '%Zone A%')sub on 
NAME LIKE '%'+sub.CAMERA+'%'
```

Expected Result

```
Result 
Vehicle   NAME
Honda     Txx_ss_ABCD
Myvi      Tyy_ss_ABCD
Vios      Tyy_ss_JUY
Proton    Tyy_ss_LOS
SUV       Lyx_ss_JUY
```

I get an error message in DB2 when I execute this

```
Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=3.69.24 SQL Code: -420, SQL State: 22018
```

Thank you

Comment: Use '||' instead of '+' to concatenate.  Like '%' || sub.camera || '%'

Comment: `LIKE` is fairly expensive, especially with leading wildcards, because it usually invalidates the use of an index to speed up the query.  Your sample test data doesn't require it at all for `Model`, and you don't appear to need the trailing wildcard for `sub.CAMERA` either (might depend on whether the field is `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, though).  Alternative form of query: `SELECT Table2.vehicle, Table2.name FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.name LIKE '%' || Table1.camera WHERE Table1.model = 'Zone A'` (this form chosen for brevity and direction of relationships).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 doesn't support the '+' symbol for string concatenation.
Use one of the following ways to get the desired result instead:

```
with 
  Table1(LocationID, Model, CAMERA) as (values
  (1, 'Zone A', 'ABCD')
, (2, 'Zone B', 'ALI')
, (3, 'Zone A', 'JUY')
, (4, 'Zone A', 'LOS')
, (5, 'Zone C', 'OMG')
)
, Table2 (Vehicle, NAME) as (values
  ('Honda', 'Txx_ss_ABCD')
, ('Myvi', 'Tyy_ss_ABCD')
, ('Vios', 'Tyy_ss_JUY')
, ('Proton', 'Tyy_ss_LOS')
, ('SUV', 'Tyb_ss_OMG')
, ('SUV', 'UUS_ss_OMG')
, ('SUV', 'Lyx_ss_JUY')
)
SELECT Vehicle,NAME
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN (SELECT CAMERA FROM Table1 WHERE Model LIKE '%Zone A%')sub on 
NAME LIKE 
'%'||sub.CAMERA||'%'
--concat(concat('%', sub.CAMERA), '%')
;
```